# Send and recv in c++ - windows simple irc client

Tags: c++, windows

A lot of irc is for linux - not for me.

I try to make own simple irc client.
But i think that there is needed to wait for "End of /MOTD command." before joining to channel.

Look at my code:

```
int connect_serv(char* server, int port, char* nick, char* channel){
    WSADATA wsaData; /* winsock stuff, linux/unix/*bsd users need not worry about this */

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &wsaData)) /* more winsock rubbish */
    {
        printf("Failed to initialise winsock!\n");
    }
    HOSTENT* resolv;
    sockaddr_in rem;

    irc_socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (irc_socket==INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Socket nie smiga: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    resolv=gethostbyname(server);
    if (!resolv)
    {
        closesocket(irc_socket);
        return 1;
    }
    memcpy(&rem.sin_addr, resolv->h_addr, 4);
    rem.sin_family=AF_INET;
    rem.sin_port=htons(port);

    if (connect(irc_socket, (const sockaddr*)&rem, sizeof(rem))==SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Failed to connect: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(irc_socket);
        return 1;
    }
    send_cmd("NICK "+char_to_str(nick),irc_socket);
    send_cmd("USER "+char_to_str(nick)+" . . :"+char_to_str(nick),irc_socket);
    send_cmd("JOIN "+char_to_str(channel),irc_socket);
}

void send_cmd(string cmd,int fpsocket){
    char sendmsg[128];
    sprintf(sendmsg,"%s\r\n",cmd.c_str());
    send( fpsocket, sendmsg, strlen(sendmsg),0 );
}
```

Comment: We see your code.  Is there a question you have about it?  Also, you may want to consult [RFC 1459](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1459) and others to learn more about the protocol.

Comment: I want to receive data from irc server.
I know only, i need to make it in other theard, but some example? How to still receive data?